# API returns JSON? Or something else?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I'm building a simple React app for a class project using the [National Weather Service](https://www.weather.gov/documentation/services-web-api) API. The idea is: get an API return for a set of latitude and longitude coordinates (which I'll expand later so that users can input their address and a separate geocoding API can return their lat/long coordinates), which contains the URL to the forecast data (using grid coordinates), use that URL to get a second API return (believe it or not this is how NWS says it should be done) which is an object which contains a nested object properties that contains a nested array periods of objects that each represent a day/night forecast, each identified with a name and number.

I have the following code successfully displaying a list of the period names (to start), but I am getting an error in console: `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`.

Internet searches (including stackoverflow) tell me this occurs because the return isn't in JSON format, but all the resources I can find on the NWS API says it returns JSON. If it didn't; I don't think I'd get anything displaying on the web page (right?), so I must be getting JSON back since I'm seeing the period names.

In addition, the names only display when I update the browser that's displaying my live server. If I refresh the page it disappears. What's going on?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

function GetForecast() {
  const [gridEndpoint, setGridEndpoint] = useState('');
  const [forecastArray, setForecastArray] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`https://api.weather.gov/points/45.5312,-122.6447`)
          .then(reply => reply.json())
          .then(json => json.properties.forecast)
          .then(link => setGridEndpoint(link))
          .then(
            fetch(`${gridEndpoint}`)
              .then(reply => reply.json())
              .then(json => json.properties.periods)
              .then(array => setForecastArray(array))
          )
      }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      {forecastArray.map((period, index) => (
        <div key={index}>{period.name}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: This error means that you got an HTML response (most likely an error of some sort) instead of a JSON. Log that `reply` before calling `json()` on it and you should see what error it is.

Comment: Response {type: 'cors', url: 'https://api.weather.gov/points/45.5312,-122.6447', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: ""
type: "cors"
url: "https://api.weather.gov/points/45.5312,-122.6447"
[[Prototype]]: Response

Comment: This looks like a normal (200) response. What do you get from the second `fetch`?

Comment: Response {type: 'cors', url: 'https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/PQR/113,103/forecast', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: ""
type: "cors"
url: "https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/PQR/113,103/forecast"
[[Prototype]]: Response

Comment: I think I got it. Had someone point out to me that `setGridEndpoint()` isn't updating `gridEndpoint` the way I have it written. I un-nested the second `fetch()`, removed `setGridEndpoint()` and it appears to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Had someone point out to me that `setGridEndpoint()` isn't updating `gridEndpoint` the way I had it written. Here's what I replaced it with.

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch(`https://api.weather.gov/points/45.5312,-122.6447`)
    .then(reply => reply.json())
    .then(json => json.properties.forecast)
    .then(link => fetch(link))
    .then(reply => reply.json())
    .then(json => json.properties.periods)
    .then(array => setForecastArray(array))
      }, [])
```